# Sphinx can not run my module on RTD but it works locally

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I have made a python package which uses CUDA code. Using `autodoc_mock_imports` I managed a CUDA dependency error due to the import of `PyCuda`. The issue I have right now is directly inside my package: at a point I try to write a Cubin `PyCuda` (mocked) would create. Locally, without GPU, it works for some reason, on RTD though, it doesn't. The error I have is this :

```
    self.compiled_source = self.try_load_cubin()
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/.../compiler_base.py", line 66, in try_load_cubin
    cubin_file.write(cubin)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'compile'
```

`compile` in this error refers to a `pycuda` function (mocked). The exact command executed is :

```
python -m sphinx -T -E -b html -d _build/doctrees -D language=en . $READTHEDOCS_OUTPUT/html
```

Again, when I run it on my local environment which doesn't have a GPU this commands works.
Would you know how ignore this part of the code or ignore the error or any type of solution ?